# Computing the norm value of $u$ using the norm of its operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, convex-analysis

Let $V$ be a normed linear space and  $g\in V^*$. Let a set R be defined by:
    \begin{equation*}
 R=\{u\in R:g(u)=1 \}.
 \end{equation*}
    How to show that the set $R$ is nonempty, convex, closed and 
     \begin{equation*}
  \inf_{u\in R}\|u\|=\frac{1}{\|g\|}.
  \end{equation*}

I tried this wrong way and lead to wrong result
     \begin{equation*}
  \inf_{u\in R}\|u\|=\frac{1}{\sup_{u\in R}\|u\|}=\frac{1}{\sup_{u\in R}\frac{\|g(u)\|}{\|u\|}}=\frac{1}{\|g\|}.
  \end{equation*}
and regarding convexity I do this:
Let $u, v\in V$ then for any $\alpha\in[0,1]$ let $s=(\alpha u+(1-\alpha)v)$ we have

$g(s)=g(\alpha u+(1-\alpha)v)=\alpha g(u)+(1-\alpha)g(v)= \alpha +(1-\alpha)=1 $ which means that g(s)=1 and hence  $s\in R$

What can I do to prove the infemum equality, and how to prove that the set is closed.
Any Help?

Comment: It looks like you are assuming that $V$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: It is infinte and my solution is absolutly wrong

Answer (score 2):

Since $g$ is nonzero, there exists $v\in V$ with $g(v)\ne0$. Multiplying by a suitable scalar, we get that $R\ne\emptyset$.

Since $g$ is continuous, $R=g^{-1}(\{1\})$ is closed. You have already done the convexity.

Note that $0\not\in R$. For $u\in R$, 
$$\tag{1}
\|g\|\geq\frac{|g(u)|}{\|u\|}=\frac1{\|u\|},
$$
so $\|u\|\geq1/\|g\|$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $v\in V$ with $\frac{|g(v)|}{\|v\|}\geq\|g\|-\varepsilon$. Let $u=v/g(v)$. Then $u\in R$ and 
$$
\|g\|-\varepsilon\leq \frac{|g(v)|}{\|v\|}=\frac1{\|u\|}.
$$
Thus $\|u\|\leq 1/(\|g\|-\varepsilon)$, and as we can do this for all $\varepsilon$,
$$\tag{2}
\inf\{\|u\|:\ u\in R\}\leq\frac1{\|g\|}.
$$
Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, 
$$
\inf\{\|u\|:\ u\in R\}=\frac1{\|g\|}.
$$

Comment: But there no information about the continuity of $f$

Comment: I assume you mean $g $. Of course there is. First, the convention is that $V^*$ denotes the bounded functionals. It it doesn't,  what does $\|g\|$ mean?